# How to change language of visual web developer 2010 express from german to english

Tags: visual-web-developer

Because all error messages are in German and Google doesn't help me to find solutions for German error messages I want to change the language of visual web developer to English.

This shouldn't be too hard, but I just cant find a way to configure the language. Google didn't help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the culture of your application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Which can be done conditionally if you only need it for debugging.

Comment: Could you be more specific? The link doesnt really tell me where I exactly find that culture why I have to do it this way.

Comment: Exception messages are shown in the language (culture) in which your application is running. By default it is German I guess buy you can override it as shown in that example.

Comment: For example when application starts you can run this:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Answer (score 1):

you got to reinstall after uninstall the program at the control panel.
when reinstall with web flatform installer, there is an option to choose a language you want.
choose the English, then start install.